# How can I deploy a non .net application with ClickOnce?

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

Is it possible to deploy a non .net application with ClickOnce? I really like the auto update feature of ClickOnce, because of this I'd love to be able to deploy all my applications with it, but not all my applications are made with .net.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use ClickOnce the same way you would with C#. One requirement of ClickOnce is the entry-point to your app must be managed code.

However, you can deploy any file along with your managed code app. The standard workaround then is to create a stub .NET exe that simply launches your unmanaged app. Then deploy all those files (the managed exe, the unmanaged exe, and dependencies) with ClickOnce.

You will probably need to use [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55.aspx) to create your ClickOnce deployment since Visual Studio just creates cookie-cutter deployments and doesn't let you configure all available options.

Comment: I know this is old, and what you say makes complete sense, but could you point where in the documentation says that ClickOnce requirement is that the entry-point app must be managed code?

Comment: I briefly looked and didn't find it. I'm pretty sure it was an MSDN article. However, rather than waste time trying to find the official documentation, just try it. Creating a couple manifests with mage only takes a few minutes.

Comment: Yes, I have tried and it doesn't seem to work. I couldn't set the entry-point. But there is always the chance I am doing something wrong, so I was researching before saying for it can not be done. Thanks for taking the time to check the documentation, I couldn't find it either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is apparently possible - at least for Visual c++ apps. It also says on the ClickOnce page for VC++ that if your dll is part of a C# project, then you can use the ClickOnce part of the C# project to deploy those dependencies as well. This suggests that you may also be able to have a tiny mock app used just to host the deployment.